# Populate Textbox with multiple values from DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have: `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdownID" })`

I want to populate a `Textbox` from this `DropDownList` with multiple values separated by comma. I tried two things but I am kinda stuck right now.

**1.**

```
    $('#dropdownID').on('change', function () {
        $("#textbox").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
})
```

This is sending one text value to the Textbox but how I make it with multiple values?

**2**

```
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdownID');

mydropdown.onchange = function () {
    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + this.value;
}
```

The second one is giving me in the `Textbox` every value I select but not the text, how I can make it to diplay the text instead the value?

I am not that good with jquery.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? Syntax in first snippet looks like Razor.

Comment: yea I populate that drop downlist from an Enum, thats all the MVC part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close with your first solution. You just need to pass the .val() function its existing value as well, like this:

```
    $("#textbox").val($('#textbox').val() + ' ' +
        $(this).find("option:selected").text());
```

Comment: To make things a bit smoother, you may want to capture the handle for the textbox element in a separate variable first: var $textbox = $('#textbox'); then use that handle: $textbox.val($textbox.val() + $(this).find('option:selected').text());

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dropdownID').on('change', function () {
    var textBox = $('#textbox');
    var previousTextBoxValue = textBox.val();
    var optionText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    textBox.val( (previousTextBoxValue ? previousTextBoxValue + ', ' : previousTextBoxValue) + optionText);
});
```